# Why doesn't my function exit if the game is played more than once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing Python by making a simple guessing game. It seems to work well, however if the user plays more than once the program won't quit even if the answer to `Play again? (y/n):` is `n`. I'm thinking it has to do with the recursion but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any pointers?

(The `print(key)` was just to make winning the game fast for debugging.)

```
import random

def guess():
    while True:
        get = input("Enter a number between 1 and 9: ")
        try:
            num = int(get)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please input an integer.")
    return num

def run_game():
    count = 0
    key = random.randint(1, 9)
    replay = None
    print(key)
    while True:
        num = guess()
        count += 1
        if num == key:
            print("Correct!")
            print("Total guesses:", count)
            replay = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
            if replay == 'y':
                run_game()
            elif replay == 'n':
                print("Thanks for playing!")
                return
        elif num > key:
            print("Too high!")
        else:
            print("Too low!")

run_game()
```

Comment: If you want to use recursion to run the game multiple times, then you need to add a `return` after the recursive call.  Note that recursing is the wrong way to do it though.  You should use an outer loop, preferably split out into a separate function (i.e. have `run_game` run a single game, and have the *caller* ask if you want to play again).  You should also do something reasonable if the user enters a value other than `y` or `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the function again recursively, but you don't exit after calling, so when the user quits from the second round, he goes back to the first round.

What you're missing is a `return` after your call to `run_game`.

ex.

```py
if replay == 'y':
  run_game()
  return
```